# JQuery Change Next Table Attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attr, closest

I am trying to change the next tables attribute after the font tag with class .rewardpoints.  Every time I try the following code It changes the cellpadding to 5 on the table ABOVE .rewardpoints.  Any ideas?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
     <tbody><tr>
        <td>
        <font></font>
        <font></font>
        <font class="text colors_text rewardpoints"><span>Earn Burkett Bucks</span></font>
             <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>

jQuery('.rewardpoints').closest('table').attr('cellpadding', '5');
```

I have also tried the following:

```
jQuery('.rewardpoints').next('table').attr('cellpadding', '5');
jQuery('.rewardpoints').nextAll('table').attr('cellpadding', '5');
jQuery('.rewardpoints').siblings('table').attr('cellpadding', '5');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) travels up the DOM tree.

> Begins with the current element
>   Travels up the
>   DOM tree until it finds a match for
>   the supplied selector

You should use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), or [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/), or [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Answer (score 0):

Use next instead of closest.

http://api.jquery.com/next/